# Deriving a reduction formula for the integral: $I_n=\int _0^1 \left(1+x^2\right)^n \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, reduction-formula

I'm trying to derive a reduction formula for the following integral:

> $$I_n=\int _0^1 \left(1+x^2\right)^n \mathrm{d}x$$

So far, I have tried applying integration by parts and have reached till:

$$I_n= x(1+x^2)^n\bigg|_0^1-2n\int_0^1 x^2\cdot (1+x^2)^{n-1} \mathrm{d}x$$

I am not able to proceed after this. The integral could be written in terms of $I_{n-1}$ but with the $x^2$ term with it, I'm not really sure how to proceed. 
I have also tried substituting $x=\tan t$ but I'm not able to derive anything significant from this either.

I would like some hints in which direction I should proceed either in the first method or in the method I have substituted for $\tan t$.
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider splitting this $x^2$ into sum of $x^2+1$ and $-1$ so you would get $I_{n-1}$ and $I_n$ on the right. Then find $I_n$ from the linear equation

Comment: This seems like a good approach! Will definitely try it out!

Comment: Yes! This was exactly what I was looking for! Thanks again.

Comment: So someone on meta was not pleased with a question I asked.. I wonder who... 

Comment: @sai-kartik Which meta post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing the derived integral:
$$I_n=(1+x^2)^n\bigg|_0^1-2n\int_0^1x^2\cdot (1+x^2)^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\Rightarrow I_n=2^n-2n\int_0^1(x^2+1-1)\cdot (1+x^2)^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x$$
$$\Rightarrow I_n=2^n-2n\left[\int_0^1(1+x^2)^n\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^1(1+x^2)^{n-1}\mathrm{d}x\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow I_n=2^n-2n\left[I_n-I_{n-1}\right]$$
$$\Rightarrow I_n =2^n-2nI_n+2nI_{n-1}$$
Solving the above linear equation in $I_n$ gives us : 
$$\boxed{I_n(2n+1)-2nI_{n-1}=2^n}$$

Answer (score 3):

I would like to investigate their difference which help us evaluate the integral easily.
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_{n}-I_{n-1} 
&=\int_{0}^{1} x^{2}\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n-1} d x \\
& \stackrel{IBP}{=} \frac{1}{2 n} \int_{0}^{1} x d\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n} \\
&=\left[\frac{x\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n}}{2 n}\right]_{0}^{1}-\frac{1}{2 n} \int_{0}^{1}\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{n} d x \\
&=\frac{2^{n-1}}{n}-\frac{1}{2 n} I_{n}
\end{aligned}
$$

Rearranging yields the reduction formula $$
\boxed{I_{n}= \frac{1}{2 n+1}\left(2^{n}+2 n I_{n-1}\right)}
$$